# Can we customize the message back to gerrit in jenkins with variable?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

In Jenkins [gerrit-trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger), we are able to customize the build message, I wonder whether we can use variable inside ?

Like below for `${PORT}` ?

[image]

**Update in 2017.03.31**, it looks there is issue already [JENKINS-37885](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37885)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use any job parameter in the format `<PARAMETER>` and any build environment variable in the format $VARIABLE.

In the Gerrit plugin help ("?") is written:

```
The following standard <PARAMETER> values are available:

GERRIT_NAME: The Gerrit project name.
CHANGE_ID: The Gerrit Change-Id (SHA-1).
BRANCH: The branch of the project.
CHANGE: The change number.
PATCHSET: The patchset number.
PATCHSET_REVISION: The patchset revision.
REFSPEC: The ref-spec. (refs/changes/xx/xxxx/z).
BUILDURL: The URL to the build.
VERIFIED: The verified vote.
CODE_REVIEW: The code review vote.
NOTIFICATION_LEVEL: The notification level. (always ALL)
The following special <PARAMETER> values are available:

STARTED_STATS: The number of builds started out of the total triggered like "(1/3)". If there is only one build triggered then the value is empty.

You can also use any environment variable from the build that was started with the $ENV_VAR syntax.
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, like ` "$GERRIT_PORT"`. it is for the build message not normal build step

Comment: I understood from your question that you were trying to use the environment variables in the build message not the gerrit-trigger plugin variables in the build step.